# Why when searching for a specific script name it's not showing all the objects with the script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example, I'm typing in the search field Cinemachine and then I see all the gameobjects that a script with the part name of Cinemachine attached to.

in this case 36 items.

for example, items 20 and 13 have the same script name: CinemachineComposer

[results of Cinemachine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oj91v.jpg)

then I'm typing and searching for Guid and it found only one item with the script GenerateGuid.
but in the Hierarchy there are more then 1 item with GenerateGuid script attached at least 3-4 objects. why it's showing only one.?

already when typing only the letter G it should show all the objects with GenerateGuid bit it's not.  it's showing only this single object.

[only one object found but there are more objects with this script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yU5MY.jpg)

the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using static Unity.VisualScripting.Member;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using log4net.Util;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameObjectAndScriptName
{
    public GameObject GameObject;
    public string ScriptName;

    public GameObjectAndScriptName(GameObject gameObject, string scriptName)
    {
        GameObject = gameObject;
        ScriptName = scriptName;
    }
}

public class ScriptFinder : EditorWindow
{
    static ScriptFinder window;
    static List<GameObjectAndScriptName> gameObjectAndScriptNames = new List<GameObjectAndScriptName>();
    Vector2 scrollPos;
    static List<int> num = new List<int>();
    static List<string> test = new List<string>();

    [MenuItem("EditorUtility/Script Finder")]
    static void OpenScriptFinder()
    {
        window = (ScriptFinder)EditorWindow.GetWindow(typeof(ScriptFinder),false,"Script Finder");
        window.minSize = new Vector2(700, 700);
        window.maxSize = new Vector2(700, 700);
        MonoBehaviour[] scripts = UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType<MonoBehaviour>();
        foreach (MonoBehaviour script in scripts)
        {
            Type scriptType = script.GetType();
            var scope = scriptType.Namespace;
            if (scope == null || !scope.StartsWith("Unity"))
            {
                if (!gameObjectAndScriptNames.Any(x => x.GameObject == script.gameObject))
                {
                    gameObjectAndScriptNames.Add(new GameObjectAndScriptName(script.gameObject, scriptType.Name));
                }
            }
        }

        Traverse();
    }

    static void Traverse()
    {
        test = new List<string>();
        foreach (UnityEngine.Transform t in UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(UnityEngine.Transform)))
        {
            test.Add(t.name);
            Debug.Log(t.name);
        }
    }

    string searchString;
    void OnGUI()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        GUI.color = Color.white;
        GUILayout.Space(30);
        searchString = GUILayout.TextField(searchString, GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachTextField"));
        if (GUILayout.Button("", GUI.skin.FindStyle("ToolbarSeachCancelButton")))
        {
            searchString = "";
            GUI.FocusControl(null);
        }

        GUILayout.Space(15);

        GUIStyle TextFieldStyles = new GUIStyle(EditorStyles.textField);
        GUI.contentColor = Color.white;
        GUI.color = Color.white;

        //Value Color
        TextFieldStyles.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        //Label Color
        EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.yellow;
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("         Overall number of GameObjects in Hierarchy: " + test.Count.ToString());
        EditorGUILayout.Space(10);
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("         GameObject                                                                                 Script");
        GUILayout.Space(5);
        EditorStyles.label.normal.textColor = Color.white;

        scrollPos =
            EditorGUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPos, false, false);


        foreach (GameObjectAndScriptName item in gameObjectAndScriptNames)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

            if (searchString != null)
            {
                if (item.ScriptName.Contains(searchString, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 25;
                    EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(),
                        item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject),
                        true);

                    counter++;
                    foreach (UnityEngine.Transform g in item.GameObject.transform.GetComponentsInChildren<UnityEngine.Transform>())
                    {

                    }

                    EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = 25;
                EditorGUILayout.ObjectField(counter.ToString(), item.GameObject, typeof(GameObject), true);

                num.Add(EditorGUILayout.TextField(item.ScriptName).Length);
                if (counter != gameObjectAndScriptNames.Count)
                {
                    counter++;
                }
            }

            EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }

        GUILayout.EndScrollView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MonoBehaviours are being excluded.

```
if (!gameObjectAndScriptNames.Any(x => x.GameObject == script.gameObject))
{
    gameObjectAndScriptNames.Add(new GameObjectAndScriptName(script.gameObject, scriptType.Name));
}
```

If my gameObject has two monobehaviours, only one of them will show up because of this filter.

The condition is essentially

```
foreach gameobject in my collection
    if this gameobject has already been added
         skip it
```

Remove that condition and it should work fine.
The list you get from FindObjectsOfType is all of the unique monobehaviours in the hierarchy.

Comment: Another hint, since the `gameObjectAndScriptNames` is a `static` you will want to make sure you also `Clear` is first .. otherwise you end up with a list growing bigger and bigger every time you ope the editor window ;)